# How to ask the user for 10 numbers and select out of the 10 the numbers that are even

Tags: c#

I am new to programming, I am trying to ask the user for 10 numbers in C# and list the numbers from the 10 numbers that are even. So far have done this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
//Jeyhun Mammadov
//maximum and minimun numbers

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbs = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                numbs[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if(numbs[i] % 2 = 0)
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know the next step to take, please I need help from someone one this. Thanks

Comment: `numbs[i] % 2 = 0` assigns the value of zero. You need an `==` in place of the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second loop to display even numbers, after you get the input from user:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     if(numbs[i] % 2 == 0)
         Console.WriteLine("{0} is even", numbs[i]);
}
```

Also you can use [`LINQ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) to get even numbers in one statement then display them together:

```
var evenNumbers = numbs.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);

Console.WriteLines("The even numbers are: {0}", string.Join(",", evenNumbers));
```

If you don't know about `LINQ` you migth want to read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx).It might seem complicated first but after you learn it you will love it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<int> numbs = new List<int>();
int num;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if(num % 2 == 0)
    {
       numbs.Add(num);
    }
}

foreach(int number in numbs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", number);
}
```